# Why would two inertial frames be distinguishable, if the coordinate of an event perpendicular to the motion would be different?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, inertial-frames

This question arises from the classical example: imagine a laboratory frame, and a space shuttle frame, the space shuttle moving in the laboratory frame with a constant velocity, let's say in the $x$ direction. Then the $y$ and $z$ coordinate of an event should be the same in both frames, otherwise we would have an experimental method to distinguish between the two frames.

What I would like to know is:

1. What do physicists mean by inertial frames not being distinguishable? @jim and @ACuriousMind's remarks make this clear, that the equivalence of inertial frames is no more and no less than physical laws taking the same form in all inertial frames. Also @ACuriousMind pointed out the "distinguishability" is not a good choice of words, with which I agree, because this is what partly causes my confusion, since there is of course most of the time some way to somehow tell two inertial frames apart. (A very trivial example would be that one looks like a space shuttle, and the other looks like a house.) However, my second question remains.
2. Why the difference in the $y$ coordinate (and, in fact usually many other quantities in the direction of the relative motion, like force, momentum, etc.) would allow an experimental method to differentiate between inertial frames, while measuring the difference between the $x$ coordinates is not considered to be such a method.

Comment: "Indistinguishable" is not a very good choice of words, a better choice would be "equivalent". All inertial frames are equivalent, i.e. equally good to describe physics because Newton's laws hold in all inertial systems (and they don't in non-inertial systems).

Answer (score 1):

What is meant is that physical laws are the same between (inertial) reference frames so that if you observe two bodies undergoing an elastic collision then you will experimentally determine that the momentum before the collision is the same as the momentum after the collision. An observer in another frame will also note that in his reference frame, the momentum before the collision will be the same after. However, if a person in the first frame communicated the values of the momenta of the particles, they would be different to his values.

Comment: How does this imply, that if the measurement of e.g. a spatial coordinate of an event perpendicular to the direction of (relative) motion would be different in two inertial frames, than we would have an experimental method to distinguish between these frames?